# How to fine-tune Allennlp's RoBERTa text entailment model on custom data?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, allennlp, roberta-language-model

I'm working on a project where I need to fine-tune [pair-classification-roberta-snli](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/main/allennlp_models/modelcards/pair-classification-roberta-snli.json) model offered by AllenNLP. I have prepared my custom dataset in the snli format but couldn't manage to find a way to retrain the model. Currently, I am following [this approach](https://github.com/dh1105/Sentence-Entailment) to train bert-base model for textual entailment. But how to fine-tune AllenNLP's pair-classification-roberta-snli model?

Comment: You can start with this training config, but change the "model" part to use the "from_archive" type: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/39557dd8a85ffedd195033ef760c1ac53caaccf9/training_config/pair_classification/snli_roberta.jsonnet#L24-L45. For example, `"model": {"type": "from_archive", "archive_file": "gs://allennlp-public-models/snli-roberta.2021-03-11.tar.gz"}`

Comment: This was a great help :D